# The created iso file cannot be installed

Tags: 16.04, server, iso

To install ubuntu remotely, I found that the machine does not recognize the NIC driver, I need to replace the NIC driver file in the iso. 
But I found that even if nothing is modified, the generated iso file can't be bootable.

I made the iso command as follows：

First, extract the iso file：

```
xorriso -osirrox on -indev ./ubuntu-16.04.3-server-amd64.iso -extract / ./test > /dev/null
```

Then, without changing the contents of the test directory. Make an iso file with the following command.

```
mkisofs -allow-limited-size -r -iso-level 3 -joliet-long -D -r -V "ubuntu-16.04.3-server-amd64.iso" -cache-inodes -J -l -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -o ./test.iso ./test
```

The output is as follows:

```
I: -input-charset not specified, using utf-8 (detected in locale settings)
Size of boot image is 4 sectors -> No emulation
  2.31% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
  3.46% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
  4.62% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
  5.77% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
  6.93% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
  8.08% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
  9.23% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 10.39% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 11.54% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 12.70% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 13.85% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 15.00% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 16.16% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 17.31% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 18.47% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 19.62% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 20.77% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 21.93% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 23.08% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 24.24% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 25.39% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 26.54% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 27.70% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 28.85% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 30.01% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 31.16% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 32.31% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 33.47% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 34.62% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 35.78% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 36.93% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 38.08% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 39.24% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 40.39% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 41.54% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 42.70% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 43.85% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 45.01% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 46.16% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 47.32% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 48.47% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 49.62% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 50.78% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 51.93% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 53.09% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 54.24% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 55.39% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 56.55% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 57.70% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 58.85% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 60.01% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 61.16% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 62.32% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 63.47% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 64.62% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 65.78% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 66.93% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 68.08% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 69.24% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 70.39% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 71.55% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 72.70% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 73.85% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 75.01% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 76.16% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 77.32% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 78.47% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 79.63% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 80.78% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 81.93% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 83.09% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 84.24% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 85.39% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 86.55% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 87.70% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 88.86% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 90.01% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:07 2019
 91.16% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:08 2019
 92.32% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:08 2019
 93.47% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:08 2019
 94.63% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:08 2019
 95.78% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:08 2019
 96.93% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:08 2019
 98.09% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:08 2019
 99.24% done, estimate finish Thu Jan 31 11:43:08 2019
Total translation table size: 2048
Total rockridge attributes bytes: 404822
Total directory bytes: 2002944
Path table size(bytes): 16516
Max brk space used 3aa000
433290 extents written (846 MB)
```

`ubuntu-16.04.3-server-amd64.iso` is downloaded from the official website, and can be installed as expected, but the `test.iso` cannot be bootable.

I've checked a lot of information but got nothing useful.

Can you help me? Or can there be other commands to make an iso file that can be bootable?

Comment: try useing a gui application like etcher.

Comment: You would have to clarify what you mean by "cannot be installed".
Does it not boot ? Can it not be mounted ?
Your mkisofs command prepares the ISO for BIOS booting from CD or DVD media 
only. ubuntu-16.04.3-server-amd64.iso has aditional boot equipment for EFI and USB sticks, like
current Debian amd64 ISOs. See https://wiki.debian.org/RepackBootableISO#Determine_those_options_which_need_to_be_adapted_on_amd64_or_i386
for an example how to repack it.

Comment: I can only make iso from the command line.

Comment: @Thomas 
Thank you for your link，
The generated iso can be bootable.